# Procedimiento sub o function no definido en Visual Basic

Tags: vba, vb

Mi codigo para hacer que el mause se mueva a un posicion no funciona, al compilarlo aparece

> Procedimiento sub o function no definido

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
Static nval As Boolean
If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyNumpad1) = 0 Then
If nval Then
BuscarPos
VolverPos
Lanzar
End If
End If
nval = CBool(GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyNumpad1))
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Timer()
Static nval As Boolean
If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyEnd) = 0 Then
If nval Then
End If
End If
nval = CBool(GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyEnd))

End Sub
```

Esos son timers

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vkey As Long) 
As Integer
Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = &H1
Private Declare Sub Keybd_Event Lib "User32" (ByVal bVK As Byte, _
ByVal bScan As Byte, _
ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
ByVal dwExtrainfo As Long)
Const HWND_TOFMOST = -1
Private Type POINTAPI
        x As Long
        y As Long
End Type





Sub clickizquierdo(xP As Long, yp As Long)
Dim junk As Long
junk = setcursorpos(xP, yp)
mouse_Event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xP, yp, 0, 0
mouse_Event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xP, yp, 0, 0
End Sub

Public Sub Lanzar()
clickizquierdo (894), (440)
End Sub

Public Sub VolverPos()
setcursorpos Form1.x.Caption, Form1.y.Caption
End Sub

Public Sub BuscarPos()
Getcursorpos pt
Form1.x.Caption = pt.x
Form1.y.Caption = pt.y
```

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo? . . . .. . .. . . . . .. . .. . . . .. . .

Answer (score 1):

Te falta declara los eventos del mouse:

```
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20
Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40
Const MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = &H1
Const MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = &H8000
Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8
Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10
Private Declare Sub SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer)
```

Codigo ejemplo para mover cursor:

```
Sub Ejemplo()
X = 1048
Y = 300
SetCursorPos X, Y
End Sub
```

Clickzquierdo, ClickDerecho etc... :

```
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0&, 0&, cButt, dwEI

mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0&, 0&, cButt, dwEI

mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0&, 0&, cButt, dwEI

mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0&, 0&, cButt, dwEI
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo. un abrazo